# Pre programar parametros a retirar de um objecto

Tags: php

Estou a fazer uma aplicação, gostava de saber se php tem alguma maneira de preprogramar as propriedades a retirar de um objecto:

EX:

```
$_datatableCollumns = array(
    'id' => array(
        'name' => 'ID',
        'obj_param' => 'id',
    ),
    'name' => array(
        'name' => 'Name',
        'obj_param' => 'name',
    ),
    'district' => array(
        'name' => 'District',
        'obj_param' => 'district->name',
    ),
);

...

$allItems = $model::all(); // retorna um array de objectos vindo da DB
$allRows = array();
foreach ($allItems as $key => $item) {
   foreach ($this->_datatableCollumns as $column => $value) {
       $allRows[$key][$column] = $item->$value['obj_param'];
   }        
}
```

O problema surge quando tento retirar informação vinda de uma relação, o codigo acima ilustra todas as linhas retiradas da tabela concelhos e tem uma relação `(belongsTo, de laravel)` com a tabela distrito. Ou seja, não consigo aceder à propriedade `district->name` (terceira coluna) mas consigo aceder ao `name` e ao `id`

Já tentei também com `$item->{$value['obj_param']}` mas também não resulta. Queria evitar usar `eval()` o mais possível

Comment: Você esta tentando acessar o array dentro do array? é isso? Se for tenta colocar "$item->$value['id']['obj_param'];" por exemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma como está fazendo não parece boa. Sempre pense que quando cair em situações complicadas onde vai ter que resolver com gambiarras grosseiras, é porque tem algo errado na lógica. Portanto, reveja a lógica.

Mas se quiser continuar, apenas tente entender o funcionamento desses exemplos:

```
/*
Não sei qual a estrutura que retorna de $allItems = $model::all();
então fiz uma estrutura simples com array. Eu sei que retorna como stdclass (objeto), mas aqui quero mostrar um exemplo com array. Mais para frente você entenderá o motivo:
*/
$item = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => 'ok'
    )
);

/*
Esse aqui seria o trecho 'obj_param' => 'district->name'
*/
$param = 'foo->bar';

/*
A lógica para montagem começa aqui. Vamos explodir num array.
*/
if (strpos($param, '->')) {

    $arr = explode('->', $param);

    /*
    Então aplicamos a função array_reduce() para chegar ao valor de $item['foo']['bar'] a partir de uma string "foo->bar"
    */
    $rs = array_reduce(
        explode('->', $param),
        function ($x, $key) {
            if (isset($x[$key])) {
                return $x[$key];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        },
        $item
    );

    /*
    Resulta em
    string(2) "ok"
    */
    var_dump($rs);


}
```

## Exemplo com objeto stdclass

A lógica é a mesma do exemplo anterior com array, por isso não incluí comentários:

```
$item = (object)array(
    'foo' => (object)array(
        'bar' => 'ok'
    )
);

$param = 'foo->bar';

if (strpos($param, '->')) {

    $arr = explode('->', $param);

    /*
    Isso aqui faz um "array_reduce" de um objeto.
    */
    $rs = function($item) use (&$rs, &$arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
            if (
                isset($item->$v)
                && is_object($item->$v)
            ) {
                unset($arr[$k]);
                $item = $rs($item->{$v});
            } else {
                unset($arr[$k]);
                return $item;
            }
        }
        return current($item);
    };

    /*
    Mostra o resultado
    */
    var_dump($rs($item));

}
```

Ambos os exemplos foram criados considerando que poderá usar N produndidade.
Exemplo:

```
$param = 'foo->bar->bar2->bar3->bar4';
$param = 'foo->bar->bar2';
$param = 'foo->bar->bar->bar';
$param = 'foo->bar';
```

## Exemplo simples, com profundidade estática

Outro modo de resolver sem complicar tanto, mas ainda assim fazendo gambiarra é se você tiver certeza do limite de profundidade das chaves do objeto.

Caso tenha somente 2, fica bem fácil pois um simples explode() já resolve metade do problema:

```
$item = (object)array(
    'foo' => (object)array(
        'bar' => 'ok'
    )
);

$param = 'foo->bar';

if (strpos($param, '->')) {
    $arr = explode('->', $param);
    var_dump($item->$arr[0]->$arr[1]);
}
```

Claro que precisa usar `isset($item->$arr[0])` antes que querer invocar `$item->$arr[0]->alguma_coisa`. Nesse exemplo me abstenho de criar verificações de consistências para simplificar a didática.

## Resumo

Você tem 3 caminhos

1. Usar eval()
   OMG no!
2. Reduzir um array/objeto iterativamente conforme exemplos acima
   É mais que uma gambiarra, é uma complicação.
3. Reescrever uma nova lógica
   Recomendado!

Comment: `allITems` é um array de objectos (rows) da Base de dados, fazendo assim não vai dar, acho que está a complicar um pouco

Comment: obviamente, conforme descrevi. Do jeito que montou a lógica só conseguirá resolver com uma baita complicação. Por isso recomendo rever a lógica, principalmente dos dados que retornam de `$model::all();`.

Comment: Obrigado, vou fazer o recomendado então