# Inserir dados em uma array multidimensional

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma array multidimensional

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [per] => Array
                (

                    [per_dep] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1115921
                            [1] => 1705572
                            [2] => 1126464
                            [3] => 1131324
                        )

                )

        )
```

E eu gostaria de alterar o valor do per_dep. Porém, essa alteração deverá ser dinâmica. Ou seja, eu tenho uma outra array com os keys.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => per
    [2] => per_dep
)
```

e tenho o valor a ser inserido

```
9999999
```

Como eu poderia realizar esse processo sabendo que será dinâmico o processo?

Eu sei que não posso fazer

```
$array.$keys = $valor
```

pois não funciona. O que eu poderia fazer?

Comment: Se possível, disponibilize o código que já tem pronto, isso ajuda na depuração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo próximo a isso:

```
    $arrayOriginal[$arrayKeys[0]][$arraykeys[1][$arraykeys[2]][$arraykeys[4]] = 9999999;
```

Sugestão de automatização:

```
  $arrayOriginal = [ 
  'a' => 0,
  'b' =>   [ 'f' => 5 , 
             'g' => [ 'h' => 4 ] ,
             'i' => [ 'o' => 5 ]
            ],
  'c' => 2,
  'e' => 5
  ];


  $arrayKeys = ['b','g','h'];



  $arrayTemp  = &$arrayOriginal;

  $i = 0;

  for ($i = 0;  $i<count($arrayKeys)-1;$i++) {
       $arrayTemp = &$arrayTemp[$arrayKeys[$i]];
  }


  $arrayTemp[$arrayKeys[count($arrayKeys)-1]] = 999999;

  print_r($arrayOriginal);
```

Saída:

```
 Array ( [a] => 0 [b] => Array ( [f] => 5 [g] => Array ( [h] => 999999 ) [i] => Array ( [o] => 5 ) ) [c] => 2 [e] => 5 )
```

Comment: certo, como automatizar isso? tipo com um foreach varrendo as keys?

Comment: Editei a resposta, ta ai um exemplo funcional, usando o código que eu sugeri :D

Comment: Muito bom!! Deu certo! Eu estou tentando aumentar a pontuação e não consigo...

Comment: ué, vota na minha resposta.

Comment: `@user5978`: se votares na pergunta o Claudio ganha pontos e pode votar na tua resposta também :) @Claudio: se esta resposta resolveu o teu problema podes marcar como aceite.

Comment: votei, só não consegui aumentar um ponto utilizando a seta para cima..

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso num array multidimensional, sendo as chaves dinâmicas, é importante saber qual a chave que você quer atualizar, coloquei um exemplo de array que pega toda a estrutura da matriz e atualiza o valor onde encontrar a chave que você procura, usando uma função recursiva, do PHP 5 ou superior, [**saiba mais aqui**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
$seuArray = array( 
  'a' => 0,
  'b' =>   array( 'b1' => 5 , 
                  'b2' => array( 'b2_0' => 4 ) ,
                  'b3' => array( 'b3_0' => 5 )
            ),
  'c' => 2,
  'd' => 5
  );

$saida = replaceValue($seuArray, 'b2_0', array('nova_chave'=>'novo_valor'));


function replaceValue($array, $key, $newValue)
{

    $params = array(
      'newvalue' => $newValue,
      'key'      => $key    
    );

    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$v, $k) use ($params) {

        if ($k == $params['key']) {
            $v = $params['newvalue'];
        }       
    }); 
    return $array;
}
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/Rzsagz)

Comment: é aí que tá o problema... do modo como você escreveu é algo fixo.. a minha array é dinâmica.. as keys são dinâmicas.. dessa forma como você colocou é algo fixo.. entende?

Comment: Entendo, mais ou menos... você precisa identificar as keys para poder trabalhar com um array, senão, não tem lógica usar o array. O valor é variável, a chave não tem que ser, está mal feito isso. Neste caso vc deveria reescrever as chaves, para um modelo comum.

Comment: Para fazer isso, existe uma função chamada [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map).

Comment: Outra coisa que vc pode fazer é resetar as keys dinâmicas desse array, usando `array_values($seuarray);`

Comment: então, como está na pergunta... eu terei uma array que são as keys... o que eu precisaria é algo que una a $array com as $keys para inserir um valor...

Answer (score 1):

A questão é muito parecida com essa: [Pre programar parametros a retirar de um objecto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122313/pre-programar-parametros-a-retirar-de-um-objecto)

A diferença é que na outra pergunta o problema é obter o acesso e o que mais complicou é que era um objeto e não um array.

No PHP, existe a função [array_reduce()](http://php.net/array_reduce) para esse propósito, mas para o seu caso, o que complica é que precisa setar e não somente ler.

Então usando uma lógica muito semelhante ao que postei na outra pergunta, fiz uma versão simples para o seu caso:

```
function SetArrayReduce($array, $key, $val)
{
    $r = array();
    $l = function($r) use (&$l, &$key, $val) {
        foreach ($key as $k => $v) {
            if (!isset($key[$k])) {
                break;
            }
            unset($key[$k]);
            if (count($key) < 1) {
                return array($v=>$val);
            }
            $r[$v] = $l($r);
        }
        return $r;
    };

    if (is_string($key)) {
        $key = explode(':', $key);
    }

    $r = $l($r);
    unset($key, $val);
    return array_merge_recursive($array, $r);
}


/*
O array com os dados originais.
*/
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'per' => array(
            'per_dep' => array(
                0 => 1115921,
                1 => 1705572,
                2 => 1126464,
                3 => 1131324
            )
        )
    )
);

/*
A chave/índice que pretende modificar.
Exemplo, para modificar somente $array[0]['per']['per_dep']

A função SetArrayReduce() aceita uma string como parâmetro.
Apenas precisa definir um delimitador. Por padrão o delimitador é :
$key = '0:per:per_dep';
*/
$key = Array
(
    0 => 0,
    1 => 'per',
    2 => 'per_dep'
);

/*
O array $key pode ser escrito de outras formas:
$key = array(0, 'per', 'per_dep');
$key = array('string1' => 0, 'string2' => 'per', 'string3' => 'per_dep');
O importante é que os valores devem estar na ordem correta pois serão agrupados em cascata.
*/

/*
Remova o comentário da linha abaixo e experimente o resultado usando $key como string.
*/
//$key = '0:per:per_dep';

/*
O valor que deseja atribuir a chave/índice.
*/
$val = 9999999;

/*
Invoca a função e mostra o resultado.
*/
$rs = SetArrayReduce($array, $key, $val);
print_r($rs);
```